# How do I import a jquery plugin into my React component? turnjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Seems like there's nothing on stackoverflow that I have searched to help me with this so far, after 30 posts.

So...
I'd like to implement this:
http://www.turnjs.com/

into my react COMPONENT.

-I tried using the script tag in the html file but react ofc doesn't recognize it when I use those functions and it gives me errors.

-I tried this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require( "./turn.min.js" );
```

But then it gives me 1000 errors about the turn.min.js syntax(cuz its all jquery). can't run anything.

[jquery undefined & syntax errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gCpX.png)

So what should I do? I really need to use this jQuery plugin.

**EDIT:**

installed it from npm but issue so far now:
[image: turn is not a function]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package is already available in the `npm` registry. So you could install the package using

`npm install turn-js`

And the import the dependency into your react project.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Turn from 'turn-js';
```

Comment: So if there was np nom package for it I wouldn't be able to use it right? Thnx for this, however, it's giving me: TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14___default(...)(...).turn is not a function

Comment: @snicks That is correct. If there is no package available in the `npm registry` you will not be able to use it. Otherwise you will have to use `require` to get the necessary lib

Comment: @snicks Also since `turn` is dependent on `jQuery` you will have to specify that in your webpack config

Comment: turn-js package on npm is not the package in question instead there is turn.js package

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been already answered but I was facing the same issue and the problem was that I was using a newer version of jQuery, like the documentation says at the end

> Latest version uses jQuery 1.12.0 because jQuery 3.x was breaking the
>   page flipper.

the package name is `turn.js` not `turn-js` you can find the package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/turn.js

I even made a [demo using React 16.10](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-turnjs-flip-magazine-vri0e). or [React class base](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-turnjs-flip-magazine-gexbk)